# Read /dev/input/eventX in bash

Tags: linux, input, io

I have a self made keyboard, which I would like to read out in a bash script.
The keyboard location is /dev/input/event1

I'm trying to read this input in bash via

```
read input </dev/input/event1
```

but that does not seems to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Input events in Linux are raw binary data; reading them in bash will require a lot of post-processing. Consider using a programming language that has at least basic handling of raw binary data.

Comment: Although answered, some extra information would be nice, like, how can we read the binary data? What does the binary data represent? How can we interpret it?

Comment: @Veda: You wouldn't do it in bash regardless, so this question is an inappropriate place for such information.